# Simple/Single layer perceptron algorithm doesn't work

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, perceptron

I am trying to grasp the ideas behind neural networks (fully) so I'm starting out by creating my own [simple perceptron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) algorithm.

Here is my code (in JavaScript):

```
var lr = 0.1;//learning rate

//Initiate the weights randomly
function initWeights(weights, trainingSets){
    for(var i=0; i<trainingSets[0].in.length; i++){
        weights[i] = Math.random()*2 - 1;
    }
    weights.push(Math.random()*2 - 1); //b
}


//Return the raw activation value for a giving trainingSet
function getSum(weights, trainingSet){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i=0; i < trainingSet.in.length; i++){
        sum += weights[i]*trainingSet.in[i];
    }
    sum += 1 * weights[weights.length-1];
    return sum;
}

//Activation function
function activate(value){
    return (value >= 0)? 1 : 0;
}

function train(weights, trainingSets){
    var error = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<trainingSets.length; i++){
        var currentSet = trainingSets[i];
        var activationValue = getSum(weights, currentSet);
        var error = currentSet.out - activate(activationValue);
        error += error;
        for(var j=0; j<weights.length-1; j++){
            var deltaW = error * lr * currentSet.in[j];
            weights[j] += deltaW;
        }
        weights[weights.length-1] += error * lr * 1;
    }
    return error/(weights.length);
}

var inp = [
    {in:[1,1], out:1},
    {in:[0,0], out:0},
    {in:[0,1], out:0},
];
var w = [];
initWeights(w, inp);
//for(var j = 0; j < inp.length; j++){
    var error = 1;
    while(error >= 0.01){
        error = train(w, inp);
    }
//}
console.log("===")
var tester = {in:[1,0], out: NaN};
console.log(getSum(w, tester)) //should be negative
console.log("y=("+w[1]+"*x+"+w[2]+")/"+w[1])
```

The results aren't consistent, (I'm using an AND algorithm to learn by).
The plot should look like:
[image: http://puu.sh/44eIY/401f63cde7.png]
But usually looks like this:
[image: http://puu.sh/44eAJ/75488a05eb.png]

I'm sure that I'm missing something small here,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three problems with your code:

- You are **redeclaring** the error variable, it was first meant to be a **summarized** error, then you declare it again as a per-output-neuron error, which leads to the lose of information reagarding the whole process
- Your stopping criterion is bad - it should be a mean **absolute** value of errors, not just sum of errors - consider simple network, which classyfies one training example of label `0` as `1`, it will result in **negative** error in your code, so training stops, even though it is far from being over
- It is not true, that after training with

  ```
  var inp = [
    {in:[1,1], out:1},
    {in:[0,0], out:0},
    {in:[0,1], out:0},
  ];
  ```

  you will get `f( [1,0] ) == 0`, this is not how perceptron works. It will simply find such a line in the 2 dimensioal plane, that `[1,1]` is on its one side, and `[0,0]` and `[0,1]` on the other. There is no guarantee, that `[1,0]` lies on the same side as `[0,0]` and `[0,1]`, and this is **expected** behaviour. With provided data, there is no reason for perceptron to not use the vertical line with `x=0.5`, which perfectly separates your data, but `f( [1,0] ) == 1`. Your training data does not "define" **and** operation, just a simple set of rules, which are obeyed by infinite number of classifiers.

  ```
  function train(weights, trainingSets){
  var error = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<trainingSets.length; i++){
      var currentSet = trainingSets[i];
      var activationValue = getSum(weights, currentSet);
      var error_current = currentSet.out - activate(activationValue);
      error += Math.abs( error_current );
      for(var j=0; j<weights.length-1; j++){
          var deltaW = error_current * lr * currentSet.in[j];
          weights[j] += deltaW;
      }
      weights[weights.length-1] += error_current * lr * 1;
  }
  return error/(weights.length);
  }
  ```

as stated in the comment, if you train your network with values for points (1,0), (0,1) and (1,1) it will infer value for (0,0) by itself

```
var inp = [
    {in:[1,1], out:1},
    {in:[0,1], out:0},
    {in:[1,0], out:0},
];

var w = [];
initWeights(w, inp);
//for(var j = 0; j < inp.length; j++){
    var error = 1;
    while(error >= 0.01){
        error = train(w, inp);
    }
//}
console.log("===")

var test = [
    {in:[1,1], out:1},
    {in:[0,0], out:0},
    {in:[0,1], out:0},
    {in:[1,0], out:0},
];

for(var i=0; i<test.length; ++i){
 console.log(test[i].in + " out: " +test[i].out + " nn: " + activate(getSum(w, test[i]) ) );
}
```

produces

```
1,1 out: 1 nn: 1 
0,0 out: 0 nn: 0 
0,1 out: 0 nn: 0 
1,0 out: 0 nn: 0
```

Comment: Heh, I was just about to write my answer with the same results.

Comment: Yes, error was re-declared, my bad (I didn't mean to do that). Also, the last point makes me confused, isn't the whole idea to give a basic set of rules (not all of them) and (hope) the network will behave accordingly?

Comment: But it does behave accordingly. Simply your set of rules is to small to expect such big generalization. There are too many possible models, which **perfectly fit** your set of rules to expect, that it will magicaly select the only one you are interested in.

Comment: @lejlot, then how can I train it for an AND rule? (without teaching it all 4 possibilities)

Comment: This is **not** what neural networks are for. In case of **and** you could train it with (0,1)->0, (1,0)->0, (1,1)->1, and it will infer (0,0)->0 by itself (only because there is no line in the R^2 space which would be consistent with those 3 values and inconsistent with the forth one), but once again **this is not what nn are for**.

Comment: @lejlot did the program (after the bug fixes) produce a good result? I even tried to give the data-set all of the possibilities and it still didn't preform well, is there another bug?

Comment: It works just fine. I copied my function to your code, added forth and value and trained it. It correctly classifies all four values. It also works for "(0,1)->0, (1,0)->0, (1,1)->1" and testing on all four, as I stated in previous comment.